# Crear registro Ajax (Laravel)

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Estoy intentando crear un `modal` que registre a una persona con su número de celular, lo quiero hacer con Ajax para que no me recargue la página ya que mas adelante habrá un `select` que se alimentará en simultáneo con la info de la base de datos.

Esto es lo que tengo:

Ruta

```
Route::post('turnos/addDeliveryModal', [App\Http\Controllers\TurnoController::class, 'addDeliveryModal'])->name('turnos.addDeliveryModal');
```

Controlador

```
public function addDeliveryModal(Request $request){
    $delivery = New Delivery();

    $delivery->nombDelivery = $request->nombDelivery;
    $delivery->celDelivery = $request->celDelivery;

    $delivery->save();

    return response()->json($delivery);
}
```

Formulario modal

```
<form method="POST" id="addDeliveryModal">
                    @csrf                
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Nombre del Delivery</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombDelivery" class="form-control form-control-alternative" required>                    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Telefono o Celular</label>
                            <input type="text" name="celDelivery" class="form-control form-control-alternative" required>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
```

Ajax

```
$("#addDeliveryModal").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let nombDelivery = $("#nombDelivery").val();
        let celDelivery = $("#celDelivery").val();
        let _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('turnos.addDeliveryModal')}}",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                nombDelivery:nombDelivery,
                celDelivery:celDelivery,
                _token:_token
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                if(response){
                    console.log("hola");
                }else{
                    console.log("hola2");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Screenshot del Formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Screenshot del error que me bota

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que con lo que yo tengo hasta ahora me bota el error que esta en la última imagen, aun soy nuevo en esto espero me puedan echar una mano.
Los leo...

Comment: El error te esta diciendo que esa ruta no esta registrada para el método POST.
A primera vista, la has definido con POST, deberías indicar tambien el fichero y si esta bajo algun middleware.
El error se puede originar si la ruta no se ha registrado. Recarga las rutas y vuelve a probar: `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Orici, antes de nada agradecer por responder. Pero desde ya te digo que si no supiera lo que dice ese error y no hubiese investigado que dice ese error no estuviese pidiendo ayuda ya que "A simple vista se puede ver que si estoy declarando el método POST tanto en el AJAX, FORM y la RUTA" creo que si te has tomado la delicadeza de leer el código ya que por algo lo estoy poniendo.

Comment: lista tus rutas POST: `php artisan r:l --method=post --compact`

Comment: Orici, https://prnt.sc/12fka59